# SOAP Object Reference

Tags: node.js, soap

I am trying to create a SOAP API call using NodeJS and the SOAP node module. I've never used SOAP before and on this instance I have no choice. I'm trying to call anything just to get the idea of how it works but even that is not working correctly.

Heres what I am using to create the call:

```
soap.createClient(url, wsdlOptions, function(err, client) {
    client.setSecurity(new soap.BearerSecurity('CHANGED-THE-TOKEN'));

    client.GetCategories(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
  });
});
```

This is giving me a 401 error code which is confusing the hell out of me.

```
{ GetCategoriesResult: 
   { Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.',
     ErrorNum: 401,
     IsError: true } }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that what's returning from `result`? Have you checked the `err` callback?

Comment: The code I posted after giving the 401 is the result. Could this be because `client.setSecurity()` is not done correctly?